# How do I change position of MongoDB/Mongoose documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm not a native English speaker. So forgive my grammatical mistakes

In Mongoose **Model.find()** will return an array of documents, where I need to change the position of the documents in the array according to user need.

For doing this I've written flowing codes 
Please go through my code and tell me that my approach is ok or not

if you can, please share a better idea for doing this type of operation

I've flowing Mongoose Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const categorySchema = new Schema(
{name: String,
position:Number
},
{
timestamps: true
}
);
const Category = model("Category", categorySchema);
```

Create some instance using this model

```
const category1 = new Category({name:'Nodejs',position:1});
await category1.save();

const category2= new Category({name:'Reactjs',position:2});
await category2.save();

const category3 = new Category({name:'Vuejs':position:3});
await category3.save();
```

Now if i query through the Category model then it will return a array of categories which is looks like this

```
const categories = await Category.find().sort({position:1});
categories // [{name:'Nodejs'},{name:'Reactjs'},{name:'Vuejs'}]
```

So if I need to move the categories position then I change the position value

```
await Category.findOneAndUpdate({name:'Nodejs'},{$set:{position:2}})
await Category.findOneAndUpdate({name:'Reactjs'},{$set:{position:1}})
```

Now categories array documents position has been changed

```
const categories = await Category.find().sort({position:1});
categories // [{name:'Reactjs'},{name:'Nodejs'},{name:'Vuejs'}]
```

When user needs to change category postion/order then user will cange the position value of the categories

**Is there any better way to doing this?**

Comment: Your approach is correct as you have taken an extra perimeter for arranging the documents.

Comment: Thak you @ShifutHossain vai.

Comment: Your approach is correct due to your data modeling. However, I'm curious to know what's your use case? How are you using the data? How is the position significant?